# Disable a nicescroll scroll bar, which is coming by default

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I am getting a nicescroll scroll bar ( red colour), by default, which is causing my html page to break when Zooming in.How to disable it.

Comment: Add some code. What have you tried ? If possible a demo of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key *horizrailenabled value* is globally set to **`true`**, in the *_globalobjects object*.  You can set the value to **`false`** which will disable the **Nicescroll** functionality, leaving the native scroll in place.

This recommendation is directly from [Nicescroll Issues Resolution](https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll/issues/114)

```
$("#yourscrollableelement").niceScroll({horizrailenabled:false});
```

To disable the native scroll with quoted key add this line:

```
$("#yourscrollableelement").css({"overflowX":"hidden"});
```

Though this is a solution, I would recommend viewing the ***Nicescroll*** code to determine what is causing issues with your mark-up.  Often times, you can solve the issue by adjusting your code.

If you pull the ***nicescroll.js*** *file* into your *editor*, *search/find* **HORIZ**.  This will most likely be where the conflict is occurring.  My guess, the *variable cursor* css property **`position: absolute;`** is the culprit.  Then you can adjust your styling and maintain *functional integrity* with the ***Nicescroll*** *library*.

Comment: Can you explain a little more clearly ? May be step wise what should I do

Comment: What is #yourscrollableelement ?

Comment: The ***#yourscrollableelement*** is whatever you have the Nicescroll attached to.  You could have this set to anything, however, without any code, there is no way for me to know for sure.  Just replace with whatever you need.  Take a look at the [nicescroll.js code](https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll/blob/master/jquery.nicescroll.js).  Pay close attention to lines ***59 - 116*** these are the global defaults and also look at lines ***938 - 1098*** follow railh and cursor.

Comment: It worked ! Thanks!